# Phonegap/Cordova 2.9 Custom Plugin creation. Any working examples?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I know there's a whole bunch of examples of phonegap/cordova plugins available on github but I'm seeing a lot of inconsistencies between how the plugins are built.  The structure looks the same (for the most part) but the code and implementation seem different for almost each one. It leaves me asking a few questions.

- The 2.9 docs say to use the  approach of declaring the plugin in the config, yet I get build warnings that say to use the  approach.  Should I use both?
- In the javascript, what is the correct way to declare/instantiate the plugin?
- Do I refer to my plugin's method via window.MyPlugin.myMethod or is it just window.myMethod?

I have more questions, but code would be amazing.

Does anyone have an absolutely simple example of a custom plugin for cordova 2.9, for the iOS platform, that works?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple plugin that I wrote a few days go, it was just to test building an iOS based Cordova plugin.

JS:

```
var tester = function() {};

tester.prototype.test = function () {
    cordova.exec(
        function(result) {
            navigator.notification.alert('test plugin returned: '+result);
        },
        function() {
            navigator.notification.alert('test plugin error');
        },
        'TestPlugin',
        'test',
        ['Your test string']
    );
};

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.tester) {
    window.plugins.tester = new tester();
}
```

Called with:

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.tester.test()">TEST PLUGIN</button>
```

TestPlugin.h:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface TestPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)test:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

TestPlugin.m:

```
#import "TestPlugin.h"
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@implementation TestPlugin

- (void)test:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* testString = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if (testString != nil && [testString length] > 0) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:testString];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

Added to /platforms/ios/{PROJECT_NAME}/Resources/config.xml:

```
    <plugin name="TestPlugin" value="TestPlugin" />
```

Comment: First off, that is a great reply.  I very much appreciate the succinct yet thorough code.  Thank you.  I'm running in to the same problem that I've been wrestling with for a few days.  When I click that test button, nothing happens.  Maybe I'm not looking for errors in the right place.  Nothing seems to show up in the console, though.  Any ideas?